# Script async/defer/onload usage in Google's API javascript samples

Tags: javascript, google-api

In various javascript samples which Google provides for its API (e.g [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/js)), they use the following code to load the script from the html:

```
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" 
    onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()" 
    onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>
```

My understanding is that `async/defer` tell the browser when to load and execute the script and somewhat contradict each other. I have few questions:

1. What is the meaning of using both `async` and `defer` in this
   context?
2. Why did Google choose to use this technique? Does it have any
   performance or other benefits?
3. In the `onload` event, why do they first assign an empty function ( `function(){};` ) to the event
   before calling `handleClientLoad()`?
4. If I want to move the entire javascript to a separate js file,
   what's the best approach to load both scripts? Since the new js file
   will depend on *api.js* and can't be loaded asynchronously?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fairly well-covered by [the WHAT-WG living standard for HTML's section on `async` and `defer`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-async), which includes this handy graphic:

[image]

> 1. What is the meaning of using both async and defer in this context?

If the browser supports `async`, it ignores `defer` and does the async work. If not but it supports `defer`, it does the defer instead. If it doesn't support either, the script blocks DOM parsing, but all modern browsers support at least one.

> 2.Why did Google choose to use this technique? Does it have any performance or other benefits?

`async` fetches the script without blocking DOM parsing and rendering, and runs it *as soon as it's available* even if DOM parsing and rendering is still underway. `defer` will also avoid blocking DOM parsing and rendering, but won't run the script until parsing is complete (e.g., potentially later).

> 3. In the onload event, why do they first assign an empty function ( `function(){};` ) to the event before calling `handleClientLoad()`?

This becomes clear if you look at `onreadystatechanged`: Basically it ensures that `handleClientLoad` is only called once by GAPI, not potentially twice (once by `onload` and once by `onreadystatechanged`.)

> 4. If I want to move the entire javascript to a separate js file, what's the best approach to load both scripts? Since the new js file will depend on api.js and can't be loaded asynchronously?

Well, it *can* be loaded asynchronously, you just have to handle the race condition with `api.js`. I'd probably:

1. Have `handleClientLoad` in an inline script above the `script` tag loading `api.js`, something like this:

   ```
   var clientLoaded = false;
   function handleClientLoad() {
       if (!clientLoaded &&
           typeof mainScriptLoad !== "undefined" &&
           typeof gapi !== "undefined") {
           clientLoaded = true;
           mainScriptLoad();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Have `mainScriptLoad` in your separate file.
3. At the end of your separate file, call `handleClientLoad`.

That way:

- If your script runs first, it'll call `handleClientLoad` but `handleClientLoad` will see that the GAPI isn't loaded yet and won't do anything; later, when the GAPI loads, *it* will call `handleClientLoad` and that will call `mainScriptLoad` because everything is ready.
- If your script runs after GAPI loads, it'll call `handleClientLoad` but `handleClientLoad` will see that your main script isn't loaded yet and not try to call it. Later, when your script loads and calls `handleClientLoad`, `handleClientLoad` will call `mainScriptLoad` because everything is ready.

Comment: Last question - why both `onload` and `onreadystatechange` are needed? For supporting different browsers?

Comment: @danielv: Yes. `script` tags didn't used to raise the `load` event, back in the mists of time, but did raise the `onreadystatechanged` event.

Comment: @danielv: Thanks! Fixed.